# mod_jk "404 Page Not Found" error when accessing root URL, Inner pages are working fine

Tags: apache, tomcat8, mod-jk

I am using Apache2.4 as a front server and Tomcat8 for my webapps with Mod_JK for load balancing and forwarding all request from Apache to Tomcat8 instance.

When accessing www.domain1.com "404 Page Not found" error is shown. Other page works fine.

```
www.domain1.com:8080       works
www.domain1.com            404 Page Not Found
www.domain1.com/about-us   works
www.domain2.com/contact    works
```

Apache Configuration

```
LoadModule jk_module  /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
JkShmFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.shm
JkLogFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompatUnparsed -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"

<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
  ServerName domain1.co.uk
  ServerAlias www.domain1.co.uk

  JkMount / worker1
  JkMount /* worker1

</VirtualHost>
```

worker.properties file

```
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=domain1.com
worker.worker1.port=8009
```

I have tried using JkAutoAlias and Document root pointing to tomcat webapps folder but nothing helped.

Comment: can you please post mod-jk.log

Answer (score 0):

```
www.domain1.com            404 Page Not Found
```

The above error is due to this mysterious /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi page. 
Clearing the browser cache will help getting out of this error.